# Persistent class does not seem to have been enhanced while accessing Google DataStore using Datanucleus JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I am getting the "class does not seem to have been enhanced" error while accessing the Google Data Store in GAE Application. This application was working fine before and was able to pull the data from gae datastore. But I recently updated the GAE SDK to the latest one, imported the project (deleted old one and recreated by importing it in eclipse in the same workspace recently because of another issue) and deployed it to GAE. Since then the web app is getting this error.

I tried few things.

1. Removed @PersistenceCapable and added it once again. (Rebuilt project after removing and saving it).
2. In App Engine Settings --> ORM, I removed src and mentioned selected the required folders.
3. In the .project file, the com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.enhancerbuilder is available.
4. The Use GWT is enabled.

   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper getJDOExceptionForNucleusException: Exception thrown
   Persistent class "Class com.ltt.MyEntity does not seem to have been enhanced. You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output." has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.
   org.datanucleus.store.exceptions.NoTableManagedException: Persistent class "Class com.lalit.learn.data.CourseEntity does not seem to have been enhanced. You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output." has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.
       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager.getDatastoreClass(DatastoreManager.java:551)

None of this resolved the issue. Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: If tagging against DataNucleus then use the DataNucleus projects enhancer so you know your classes are enhanced. The rest of that is Google code and they don't support their own code

Comment: Rolled back to to the older GAE SDK (1.9.25) in new workspace. Finally the app started working fine as before. Not sure which one resolved the issue. The GAE SDK 1.9.42 is giving other JSP compilation errors at the deployment time. Debugging JSP compilation errors is another challenge in eclipse. Will post the results after resolving the compilation issues.